# Create Docker Service for Autoplotter Python Library

Tags: python, django, docker, django-templates, dockerfile

I want to create a docker service for [Autoplotter](https://pypi.org/project/autoplotter/) , and want to show its output in `iframe` which I can later show in my django templates ? Is it possible if yes please need guideline. Thank you

Comment: Autoplotter seems to be a GUI tool. How do you imagine the service interface you create to look? And how do you imagine getting the data from the service into Autoplotter?

Comment: I am anticipating that i have data in postgresql and i will make a data frame (df) like this --> data= Employee.objects.all().values()
    df= pd.DataFrame(data) and  convert that dataframe to iframe  which then be interfaced with my service running in docker. I am also thinking that if one can convert a datafraem into df.to_html() than there would be something that can convert the GUI output in iframe which can be later shown through docker service. Further your guideline is require if it will really work?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create Dockerimage file as your needs and then run it with docker-compose.yml file or docker run command
Now I put to example of Dockerfile and compose file that I use for my python projects, but you have to change some value like port or ... as your needs.
Here`s the Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM python:3.8.6

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . ./

# For Django - replace given ip and port
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "makemigrations"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "makemigrations", "app_name"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "migrate", "app_name"]
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

x-common-config:
   &common-config
   environment:
     TZ: Asia/Tehran
   logging:
     driver: "json-file"
   options:
     max-size: "100m"
     max-file: "10"

services:

  app_name:
      image: image_name:latest
      hostname: hostname
      container_name: app_name
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      networks:
        - network_name
      << : *common-config

networks:
  axaz:
    name: axaz
```

if you use django framework be sure to change DEBUG to False and set '0.0.0.0' in allowed-hosts